# 404 after creating store

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I tried creating a new store in my magento and i follow all the steps on the tutorial.

```
ex:https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento-multistore.htm
```

After following all steps for test purposes in my index page i changed the code bellow just to see if everything looks ok in the new store:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

to 
Mage::run("nameCode", "nameType");
```

But i get a 404 not found page, cant figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new store then you dont need anything to access it in index.php file. When you create new store then it will display in dropdown in frontend. You just need to select store from dropdown.